# How do I sum the column values in a nested list without using any imports or the sum function?

Tags: python

I have been asked to find the sum of the first value in each column in a nested list. How do I do this without using imports or the sum function?

```
 def column_sums(square):
    """Returns the sum of the columns"""

    result = []
    i = 0
    for element in square:
        n = 0
        for item in element:
            if item == element[n]:
                i = i + item
        n = n + 1
    result.append(i)
    i = 0
    return result

square = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
print(column_sums(square))
```

This is what I have come up with but it only returns the value of the first column. How can I get the sum of all the columns set out like this?:

```
[28, 32, 36, 40]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you written any pseudocode/design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a purely loop based approach without any built-ins:

```
def column_sums(square):
    result = [0] * len(square[0])
    for row in square:
        for i in range(len(result)):
            result[i] += row[i]
    return result
```

The following uses the `zip(*...)` transpositional pattern:

```
def column_sums(square):
    result = []
    for col in zip(*square):
        total = 0
        for num in col:
            total += num
        result.append(total)
    return result

square = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
print(column_sums(square))
# [28, 32, 36, 40]
```

Note that you get the columns by zipping the rows. If you could use `sum` and all other built-ins, the following would be the shortest:

```
print(list(map(sum, zip(*square))))
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. I didn't know about zip(* )!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
def column_sums(square):
    result = dict.fromkeys(len(square), 0)
    for i, v in enumerate(zip(*square)):
        for x in v:
            result[i] += x
    return result

square = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
print()
```

Or with `sum` you can actually just use:

```
square = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
print(column_sums(square))
```

Comment: *"How do I do this without [...] the sum function?"*

Comment: Nope, wasn't me

Comment: `sum` is disallowed as per OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the simplest sol that came to my mind without using any fancy stuff.

```
def column_sums(square):
    """Returns the sum of the columns"""

    result = [0,0,0,0]
    for element in square:

        for i,item in enumerate(element):
                result[i] = result[i] + item   
    return result
```